# How to create a program that automatically presses buttons on a webpage

Tags: automation

I need to create a program that would allow me to automate some of my work. I am required to press buttons on a webpage depending on whether or not a certain criteria is met (the criteria would be certain keywords).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyautogui module in Python can be used for simulating mouse movements and clicks. Here is an example to move to coordinate (100,100) and to click

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)
pyautogui.click()
```

It is surprisingly easy. You can read [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](http://www,azon.ly/eCOa)

Answer (score 0):

Possible. 2 way to do this.

1. Writing a chrome extension
2. Write a windows form application which contains web component.